# Write slightly different CSS for Parent Menu Item

Tags: html, css, joomla, menu, parent

everybody!

Got into a bit of a trouble here.

So, basically, I badly want to make my Parent Menu Items in Joomla! main menu slightly different then other Menu Items. What I want to achieve is that the Parent Item would have ... let's say, a little triangle made with bg image on the right to show visitors there are some submenus included.

I've been trying to get my CSS working, but somehow nothing happenes and with inspecting the generated code and elements CSS hasn't applied anything to the Parent Items.

Here's the code:

```
<li class="item-101 current active"><a href="/" >Domov</a></li>
<li class="item-107"><a href="/index.php/o-meni" >O meni</a></li>
<li class="item-108 deeper parent"><a href="/index.php/psihoterapija" >Psihoterapija</a>
    <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
        <li class="item-113"><a href="/index.php/psihoterapija/podmeni-1" >Podmeni 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="item-109"><a href="/index.php/zdravstvena-psihoterapija" >Zdravstvena psihologija</a></li>
<li class="item-114 deeper parent"><a href="/index.php/ponudba" >Ponudba</a>
    <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
        <li class="item-117"><a href="/index.php/ponudba/podmeni-2" >Podmeni 2</a></li>
        <li class="item-118"><a href="/index.php/ponudba/podmeni-3" >Podmeni 3</a></li>
        <li class="item-119"><a href="/index.php/ponudba/podmeni-4" >Podmeni 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="item-139 deeper parent"><span class="nav-header">Ostalo</span>
    <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
        <li class="item-138"><a href="/index.php/ostalo/aktualno" >Arhiv novic</a></li>
        <li class="item-116"><a href="/index.php/ostalo/povezave" >Povezave</a></li>
        <li class="item-115"><a href="/index.php/ostalo/kontakt" >Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

So, the items I want to change are those with .deeper.parent class.

The CSS code I wanted to apply but doesn't work:

`#navigation .parent {
    padding:37px 22px 37px 8px !important;
    background-image: url(../images/more.png) !important;
    background-position: right !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}`

I also tried changing `#navigation .parent` to `#navigation .deeper.parent` and to `#navigation li.item-108.deeper.parent` as well. Nothing really works. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Where is the element with the `navigation` ID?

Comment: The correct value for `background-position` is `right center`, not just `right`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming some coding here for display purposes, but what you want here is this part:

```
#navigation li.parent { padding:37px 22px 37px 8px !important; background:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Arrow-down-navmenu.png)  no-repeat right center}
```

You can [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kt6kxL9g/) and the adjust at will (REMEMBER: I'm assuming your code so you'll have to adjust it to your real code!)

Comment: Hm, I got it working somehow ... but ONLY if I use the code like this: li.parent {
 padding-right:7px !important;
    background-image: url(../images/more.png) !important;
    background-position: right center !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}

#navigation li.parent { 
 padding-right:7px !important; 
 background:url(../images/more.png)  no-repeat right center}

I can't use only target one of those, have to use both to have effect.

Comment: again, I'm ASSUMING you had that code because you mentioned a navigation div. You MUST change it to suit your needs, and it's impossible that you have to target an element twice to make it work, be sure to check because you're missing something, probably targeting a wrong element

Comment: Your code works now, didn't really change anything for my needs. Had to do complete rewrite of the CSS for the menu, something must have been in the way. I've been targeting the right element for the whole time, but ... my bad, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ensure you actually have the `#navigation` ID assigned to your `<ul>` like so:

```
<ul id="navigation">
```

Secondly, make sure you do **not** target menu items based on their item number, such as `.item-108`. These are assigned by Joomla and may change in the future.

Ok, so as you mentioned, you want to target menu items with the `deeper` and `parent` classes, for this, you can use the following:

```
.deeper.parent a {
    background: url(../images/more.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
    height: 12px;
}
```

Note that I have used `right center` to define the **X** and **Y** axis, and also defined the height of the image, which may be different for you.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey, thanks for quick answer. It didn't work. With inspecting the element in Chrome, Firefox or Safari I still can't see the code that should be applied. P.s.: Well, #navigation is there because menu is inside div with ID "navigation". So, that should be no problem. I usually never target item numbers, I only did it this time to see what happens if I target the whole thing.